# jQuery targeting and moving specific elements one by one

Tags: jquery, indexing, insertafter

I have an HTML structure like so:

```
<tr class="v65-productDisplay-row"></tr>
<tr class="v65-productDisplay-row PriceAndButton"></tr>
<tr class="v65-productDisplay-row PhotoLine"></tr>
<tr class="v65-productDisplay-row"></tr>
<tr></tr>
<tr class="v65-productDisplay-row"></tr>
<tr class="v65-productDisplay-row PriceAndButton"></tr>
<tr class="v65-productDisplay-row PhotoLine"></tr>
<tr class="v65-productDisplay-row"></tr>
<tr></tr>
<tr class="v65-productDisplay-row"></tr>
<tr class="v65-productDisplay-row PriceAndButton"></tr>
<tr class="v65-productDisplay-row PhotoLine"></tr>
<tr class="v65-productDisplay-row"></tr>
<tr></tr>
...and so on
```

I am trying to target each PriceAndButton TR and insert it after each corresponding PhotoLine TR. Here is the code I have so far but it's not working as of yet:

```
        jQuery(".PriceAndButton").each(function() {
            var IndexValue = $(this).index();
            $(this).insertAfter(".PhotoLine:eq(" + IndexValue + 1 + "");
        });
```

My thoughts were to get the index value of each PriceAndButton element and insert it after the PhotoLine TR where its eq equals the index value + 1. This should work right since the PhotoLine TR is always immediately after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code (I fixed the closing parenthesis):

```
".PhotoLine:eq(" + IndexValue + 1 + ")";
```

will concatenate as a string. If `IndexValue` equals 3, then you'll get the string `.PhotoLine:eq(31)` instead of `.PhotoLine:eq(4)`. What you meant was:

```
".PhotoLine:eq(" + (IndexValue + 1) + ")";
```

But even then it won't work quite right.

For simplicity, you can avoid using `eq` at all by instead selecting `.next('.PhotoLine')` (or just `.next()`, but I like to be accurate to avoid unexpected surprises):

```
$('.PriceAndButton').each(function(i,el) {
    $(this).insertAfter($(this).next('.PhotoLine'));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/YWaYN/

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the jQuery [next method](http://api.jquery.com/next/) like so:

```
$(".PriceAndButton").each(function() {
    var self = $(this);
    self.insertAfter(self.next());
});
```